# C# Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput=true does not return redirected output nor error

Tags: c#, stdio, io-redirection

I have some code that launches a process "python.exe", the redirected output would return stream from the process if I set process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput=false, output is available and processed by readOut() or readErr() thread handlers.  However, if I set it to true I wouldn't get any output from the process.  I need the input redirection so I can send inputs to the process from a Windows form.

I do have 2 threads one processes the redirected output the other processes the redirected stderror.  I appreciate if you can provide some pointers.  Thank you.

My code goes like this:

```
        ....
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //output is available and processed by readErr if this set to false.
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = this.exe;

        readTh = new Thread(readOut);
        readTh.Name = "CmdStdOutTh";
        errTh = new Thread(readErr);
        errTh.Name = "CmdStdErrTh";

        lock (this)
        {
            p.Start();
            readTh.Start();
            errTh.Start();
        }
    ....

    void readOut()
    {
        char[] buf = new char[256];
        int n = 0;
        while ((!p.HasExited || (p.StandardOutput.Peek() >= 0)) && !abort) {
            n = p.StandardOutput.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length - 1);
            buf[n] = '\0';
            if (n > 0)
                processOutput(new string(buf));
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }

    void readErr() {
        char[] buf = new char[256];
        while ((!p.HasExited || (p.StandardError.Peek() >= 0)) && !abort) {
            int n = p.StandardError.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length - 1);
            buf[n] = '\0';
            if (n > 0)
                processError(new string(buf));
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to wait until p is done, using

```
p.WaitForExit();
```

That seems to be missing from your example. As far as I can tell the rest is correct, though perhaps could be written better: as written, it looks like if there's no output available your code would spin, waiting. That's going to burn CPU unnecessarily. Instead, just go ahead and call Read: it'll block until there's enough, so this will release the CPU for other threads or processes.

Comment: I have p.WaitForExit() in my code which is not included here.  Back to the original question, the problem I have with the above code is that I'm not getting the output from the executable (Python.exe) if I had RedirectStandardOutput=true.  It works fine if I have that set to false, I'll get the Python banner coming back on readErr()'s buf which reads "Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32".  Why is there nothing in the pipe?  I have 2 threads here servicing it as the bits come in on read and errors IO.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem.  The "p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true" is working correctly.  The problem is in Python.exe.  I've to use the "-i" arg option for StartInfo.Arguments.  It's explained in

[Redirect Python standard input/output to C# forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380649/redirect-python-standard-input-output-to-c-sharp-forms-application?rq=1)