# DataReceivedEvent not hit while Interacting with (Python) process from redirected input/output/error

Tags: c#, python, winforms, stdout, stdin

I am trying to control a python session from C# using standard input & output.

After starting Python process, I expect to continue sending commands to it and receive the output to my WinForms Textbox.

After trying many SO answers and MSDN, any suggestions on why the `DataReceivedEvent` Handler is not invoked ? Full Code follows:

Note that to generate Newline from Python, I enter this in the Command Text `import os;print os.linesep`

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Process InterProc;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InterProc = new Process();
            InitializeInterpreter();
        }

        private void InitializeInterpreter()
        {
            InterProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            InterProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
            InterProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            InterProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            InterProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            InterProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            InterProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            InterProc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(InterProcOutputHandler);

            bool started = InterProc.Start();

            InterProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }

        private void AppendTextInBox(TextBox box, string text)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((Action<TextBox, string>)AppendTextInBox, OutputTextBox, text);
            }
            else
            {
                box.Text += text;
            }
        }

        private void InterProcOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            AppendTextInBox(OutputTextBox, outLine.Data + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void Enterbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InterProc.StandardInput.WriteLine(CommandTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380649/redirect-python-standard-input-output-to-c-sharp-forms-application?rq=1 In short the solution was to force python in interactive mode by passing "-i" argument to it. I could have searched better :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is for people who land up here wanting yet another among many answers out there on SO.*

The code which finally got interacting with python session is given below:
Note 1: Invoke Python with '-i' argument. *(refer Process Arguments `-i` below)*
Note 2: Trying synchronous read from std error freezed ( `Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`). So both the std output and error streams needed to be provided with a handler call back *(refer `InterProcOutputHandler` below)*

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Process InterProc;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InterProc = new Process();
            InitializeInterpreter();
        }

        private void InitializeInterpreter()
        {
            InterProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
            InterProc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-i"; // drops python into interactive mode after executing script if passed any
            InterProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            InterProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            InterProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            InterProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            InterProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            InterProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            InterProc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(InterProcOutputHandler);
            InterProc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(InterProcOutputHandler);

            bool started = InterProc.Start();

            InterProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            InterProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        }

        private void AppendTextInBox(TextBox box, string text)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke((Action<TextBox, string>)AppendTextInBox, OutputTextBox, text);
            }
            else
            {
                box.Text += text;
            }
        }

        private void InterProcOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            AppendTextInBox(OutputTextBox, outLine.Data + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void Enterbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InterProc.StandardInput.WriteLine(CommandTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help others for whom the solution above did not work.
I have been having exactly the same problem and been struggling with it and eventually found this question and answer.

For me, the `StdError` via `ErrorDataReceived` was being triggered for Error output and it was just the `Stdout` via `OutputDataReceived` which was not triggered.

I was running dotnet core on Linux (Raspberry Pi), but I also had the same problem running this on Windows.

My code was basically the same as the answer from vijiboy, so I added the `-i` option to Python, but it made no difference! But it inspired me to look closer at the Python options where I found this:

> -u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;
> this option has no effect on stdin; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x

so adding -u when calling Python (removing -i) solved the issue, and finally `OutputDataReceived` was triggered!