# Pipe to python process from c# unity

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine

I have a unity (C#) app that is calling a python script by initialising a child process.

When trying to write to the python std::in, I seem to be getting a

```
write fault on path
```

error when writing to STD::IN.

When reading from the process's STD::OUT, I get null as a value output.

What's the best way to pipe to the python process for input/output?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class PythonCaller : MonoBehaviour
{
private string buffer = "";
private Process pythonML;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    this.pythonML = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    this.pythonML.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
    this.pythonML.StartInfo.Arguments =
        "{{path to python executable}}/python {{path to python script}}/test.py";
    this.pythonML.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    this.pythonML.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    this.pythonML.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    this.pythonML.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    this.pythonML.Start();
    this.pythonML.BeginOutputReadLine();
    this.pythonML.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) => {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(e.Data);
    });
    this.pythonML.WaitForExit();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    foreach (char c in Input.inputString) {
        if (c == '\b') {
            if (this.buffer.Length > 0) {
                this.buffer = this.buffer.Substring(0, this.buffer.Length - 1);
            }
        } else if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
            try {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(this.buffer);
                this.pythonML.StandardInput.WriteLine(this.buffer);

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(e.Message);
            }

            this.buffer = "";
        } else {
            this.buffer += c;
        }
    }
}
```

}

PYTHON CODE:

```
print('hello world!')
```

Comment: Add the Python code that reads from stdin as well please.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment, I'm still getting the error InvalidOperationException: Standard input has not been redirected
System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput ()

Comment: It looks like your Python code has a `return` statement that would allow the `while` loop to execute exactly once. So, you'd only be looking to accept input for a short amount of time so it's possible the Python code isn't receiving when the C# code sends

Comment: It has been removed to little effect (it wasn't the cause in the first place as it was outside of the while loop). also looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380649/redirect-python-standard-input-output-to-c-sharp-forms-application which hasn't helped

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but have you tried debugging through this code? If so, can you tell me what the value of `StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput` is after you get the `Process` is?

Comment: Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
  UnityEngine.Debug.Log(process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput);
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false ;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
outputs false

Comment: All that appears to be correct. The only problem remaining that I could think of would be trust issues. In order for two applications to communicate this way, they must have full trust. Can you verify that?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171592/write-to-stdin-of-a-running-process-in-windows) it might not be possible if the process is already running. You could try using sockets though

Comment: Okay I'll try using sockets. I was attempting to avoid using anything involving the network layer but that's fine

Comment: If you don't mind having the C# program start the Python program then you could possibly get around it. Otherwise, it seems like it'd be a more difficult prospect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181751/discussion-between-loveen-dyall-and-woody1193).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to redirect standard input for this to work. You already have that line, it's just commented out.

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

Check this [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_RedirectStandardInput) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're writing to `StandardInput` from the C# side is how I would expect it to work, given [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46c91711-755f-48fa-a4a8-92956082218f/howto-launch-process-and-write-to-its-stdin?forum=netfxbcl) and assuming that you already tried to run your method with `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput` set to `true`. So, the only way I could see this not working is if your Python code (which you should attach to the question) wasn't reading `stdin` properly.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python), you can do that by either reading `sys.stdin` like a file, prompting the user for input or getting command-line arguments. Since you stated that your Python program is currently running, my guess is that you want to use either `read` or `readlines` to do that. Note that after you've done that you should uncomment `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;`.